# javascript: difference between scrollTop and offsetTop

Tags: javascript, scroll, offset

Is there a predictable relationship between cummulative `offsetTop` of an `<a>` element and the value of `scrollTop` after navigating to that `<a>` element?

I had naively assumed they would be equal, but I've encountered cases where `scrollTop` is larger (the scroll position is further down the page).

The following defines the question more precisely:

```
function TotalOffsetTop (e)
{
    var offset = 0;
    do 
        offset += e.offsetTop;
    while (e = e.offsetParent);
    return offset;
}

//navigate to MyBookmark
location.hash = "#MyBookmark"

var BookmarkOffsetTop = TotalOffsetTop(document.getElementByID("MyBookmark"));   
var CurrentPosition = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].scrollTop;

if ( CurrentPosition != BookmarkOffsetTop ) alert("Design Flaw!");
```

My ultimate goal is to find the nearest `<a>` tag whose start is above the top of the current viewport. This is so I can jump backward (and forward) to bookmarks relative to the current position in a document.

Are there some other measures I should be using instead of `scrollTop` and cummulative `offsetTop`?

I'm exploring the problem using Chrome, but I'd like to ultimately find something that works in at least several modern browsers. I'm trying to avoid jQuery.

Comment: +1 for trying to avoid jQuery

Comment: Hope you can accept the answer no?

Answer (score 6):

The main difference without getting into too much detail:

offsetTop is read-only, while scrollTop is read/write.
According to this, you'd be on the safer side if you were to use offsetTop:

> Be careful about the scrollTop property of the html element!
>
> In Internet Explorer earlier than version 8, it retrieves the scroll
>   amount in physical pixel size, while from version 8, it returns the
>   amount in logical pixel size. What does it mean? If the browser is not
>   at the normal zoom level (the user has the ability to zoom in or out a
>   web page: CTRL and +, CTRL and -), the scrollTop property works
>   differently from version 8 than in earlier versions.
>
> The scroll amount is calculated in the default pixel size in Internet Explorer before version 8 even if the current pixel size in
>   the document is different.
>       From Internet Explorer 8 and in Firefox, Opera, Google Chrome and Safari, the scroll amount is calculated in the current pixel size.
>
> For example, if the zoom level is 200%, the scrollTop property
>   retrieves two times greater values before version 8 than from version
>   8 for the same scroll position.

Source for the text and more info on the two:
[Source](http://help.dottoro.com/ljnvjiow.php)

Comment: Thanks! My question was seeking a way to calculate the difference between them, but this gives me an idea for refactoring to avoid the problem of `location.hash = "#MyBookmark"` scrolling to an unexpected position.